# Ran out of Docker disk space

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have this Docker command:

```
docker run -d mongo
```

this will build and run a mongodb server running in a docker container

However, I get an error:

```
no space left on device
```

I am on MacOS, and using the newer versions of Docker which use hyper-v instead of VirtualBox (I think that's correct).

Here is the exact error message from the `mongo` container:

```
$ docker logs efee16702c5756659d563b98d4ae0f58ecf1f1bba8a54f63443c0ae4b520ab4e
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 21
2017-05-04T20:23:51.412+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-05-04T20:23:51.430+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /tmp/tmp.Lo035QkbfL: No space left on device
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Any idea how to fix this and prevent it from happening in future?

As suggested, the output of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     465Gi  116Gi  349Gi    25% 1963838 4293003441    0%   /
devfs          183Ki  183Ki    0Bi   100%     634          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /home
```

Output of `docker info` is:

```
$ docker info
    Containers: 5
     Running: 0
     Paused: 0
     Stopped: 5
    Images: 741
    Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
    Storage Driver: overlay2
     Backing Filesystem: extfs
     Supports d_type: true
     Native Overlay Diff: true
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
    Plugins: 
     Volume: local
     Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
    Swarm: inactive
    Runtimes: runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Init Binary: docker-init
    containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
    runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
    init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
    Security Options:
     seccomp
      Profile: default
    Kernel Version: 4.9.13-moby
    Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
    OSType: linux
    Architecture: x86_64
    CPUs: 4
    Total Memory: 1.952 GiB
    Name: moby
    ID: OR4L:WYWW:FFAP:IDX3:B6UK:O2AN:UVTO:EPH6:GYSV:4GV4:L5WP:BQTH
    Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): true
     File Descriptors: 17
     Goroutines: 30
     System Time: 2017-05-04T20:45:27.056157913Z
     EventsListeners: 1
    No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
    Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    Experimental: true
    Insecure Registries:
     127.0.0.0/8
    Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: What is the storage driver in use?  Run `docker info | grep Storage`.  Is there free space in the host?  Run `df -h`

Comment: Storage Driver: overlay2

Comment: df -h output is in question

Comment: Show me the output of these 2 commands:

`docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Volumes }}' efee16702c5`

`docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Binds }}' efee16702c5`

Comment: sure thing, here we go: Error: No such object: efee16702c5

Comment: I get that error for both commands. however, I just deleted a bunch of crap, using these instructions: https://lebkowski.name/docker-volumes

Comment: Use the name of the mongo container instead of efee16702c5`.  Use `docker ps` to figure it out.

Comment: @RicardoBranco what do you think of the instructions in the link I just posted?

Comment: There's a lot of disk space in the host, so I don't think there's a problem.  I want to find out if /tmp is somehow in a special partition like tmpfs.

Comment: got it, let me get the container id for the mongo container and run the docker inspect commands

Comment: docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Volumes }}' 458844105e88 =>
map[/data/configdb:{} /data/db:{}]

Comment: docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Binds }}' 458844105e88 => []

Comment: hopefully the output of those two commands helps, thanks

Comment: I used docker ps to get the container id of mongo, so this should be correct

Comment: that could be, what exactly is your suspicion?

Comment: Since you are on mac, can you post the output of `ls -altrh Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`?

Comment: I don't think /Library/Containers exists as a dir on my MacOS machine

Comment: Sorry, it's `~/Library/....`

Comment: yeah I was thinking that, let me try it

Comment: here is the output =>  -rw-r--r--@ 1 alexamil  staff    53G May  4 17:23 /Users/alexamil/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

Answer (score 3):

As you state in the comments to the question, `ls -altrh ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.‌​amd64-linux/Docker.q‌​cow2` returns the following:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alexamil staff 53G
```

This is a known bug on MacOS (actually, not only) and an official dev comment could be found [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-space-left-on-device-error/10894/2). Except for one thing: I read, that different people get different size limit. In the comment it is 64Gb, but for another person it was 20Gb.

There are a couple walkarounds, but no definite solution that I could find.

#### The manual one

Run `docker ps -a` and manually remove all unused containers. Then run `docker images` and remove manually all the intermediate and unused images.

#### The simplest one

Delete the `Docker.qcow2` file entirely. But you will lose all images and containers. Completely.

#### The less simple

Another way is to run `docker volume prune`, which will [remove all unused volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)

#### The resizing one (keeps the data)

Another idea that comes to me is to expand the disk image size with QEMU or something like it:

```
$ brew install qemu
$ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/qemu-img resize ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2 +5G
```

After you expanded the image, you will need to run a VM in which you should run GParted against Docker.qcow2 and expand the partition to use added space. You could use [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/download.php) ISO for that:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=Docker.qcow2  -m 512 -cdrom ~/Downloads/gparted-live.iso -boot d -device usb-mouse -usb
```

Some people report this either doesn't work or doesn't help.

#### Yet another resizing one (wipes the data)

Create a substitute image with desired size (120G):

```
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 ~/data.qcow2 120G
$ cp ~/data.qcow2 /Application/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/moby/data.qcow2
$ rm ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

`data.qcow2` is copied to `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2` when you restart docker.

This walkaround comes [from this comment](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-space-left-on-device-error/10894/26).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, will look into it tomorrow, looks like some useful info

Comment: I thought you could just do a `docker prune image` to kill all the dangling image and `docker prune container` to remove all the exited container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have docker desktop you can simply go to "Settings" (top right cog icon) and increase the disk image size under "Resources".